# KendoGrid virtualization add new row

Tags: javascript, dojo, telerik, kendo-grid

I am trying out KendoUI trial version. I have a Grid with scrollable virtual: true.
I want to add a new row with my code.

`this.kendoGrid.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.insert({Id: 1, Title: 'test'});`

The new row is added, but when i scroll down i get error "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Here is the code to try:

`http://dojo.telerik.com/UFuwi`

**My question:**

Is this a bug or am I just adding this row not in the correct way?
If so, i cannot find anywhere in documentation a proper way to Add, delete and update the grid that is bind to local data.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the documentation, what you missed is to define the position of the new element to be inserted.

```
 var pos = test.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total() - 1;
 test.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.insert(pos, {
   Id: 3, FirstName: 'test2'
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: insert method can take position as argument, but add method does not need this. but both methods gives the same "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in console. so that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry my fault!! I didn't understand good your question. What you are experiencing is a bug from kendo grid because Virtual Scrolling uses rangens instead of pages, therefore when you add or deleted an itedm is inserted in a range, which will be recalculate when you scroll again.  Miscalculation range issue.